# Renombrar archivos XML usando python

Tags: python, xml

mi codigo intenta renombrar todos los archivos XML que se encuentran en una carpeta despues de obtener un dato dentro de este, pero al momento de hacerlo, renombra el primer archivo con el ultimo nombre que encuentra, alguna sugerencia?
Gracias!

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = 'C:/Users/....'

fnames = [ arch.name for arch in os.scandir( root ) if(arch.is_file() ) ]

infiles = [open( root + fname, "r", encoding = "utf-8").read()for fname in fnames]

columnas = []

for contents in infiles:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
    Emisores = soup.find('cfdi:Emisor')

    try:
        EmisorNombre = Emisores.get('Nombre')
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

    print(EmisorNombre)


    for file in os.listdir(root):

         os.rename(os.path.join(root,file),
                   os.path.join(root,EmisorNombre+".xml"))
```

Comment: ¿Está correcta la identación? Pareciera que el os.rename sólo se ejecuta una vez, tras finalizar el ciclo for (y no dentro del ciclo)...

Comment: Disculpa, no, no esta correcta en un momento la corrijo.

Comment: Me parece que todavía no está correcta la identación. Tal cual está, el primer for te va a regresar el último emisor del contenido del último archivo.
Luego de ahí va a recuperar el EmisorNombre (sólo uno). Con ese emisorNombre va a intentar renombrar cada uno de los archivos en la ruta, me parece que eso te va a generar error.

Comment: Tienes razon al parecer el ciclo for esta detenido y solo hace oda la operacion para uno solo, de hecho renombra correctamente el ultimo archivo pero ya no sigue haciendo el ciclo para los demas, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el último for. Intentas renombrar todos los archivos con el mismo nombre del emisor.

Una alternativa sería evitar ese último ciclo colocando una referencia al nombre del archivo cuyo contenido se está procesando en el for externo. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = 'C:/Users/....'

fnames = [ arch.name for arch in os.scandir( root ) if(arch.is_file() ) ]

infiles = [open( root + fname, "r", encoding = "utf-8").read()for fname in fnames]

columnas = []
i=0 #Se agrega contador
for contents in infiles:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
    Emisores = soup.find('cfdi:Emisor')

    try:
        EmisorNombre = Emisores.get('Nombre')
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

    print(EmisorNombre)
    os.rename(os.path.join(root,fnames[i]),os.path.join(root,EmisorNombre+".xml"))
    i+=1 #Siguiente archivo. "i" se utiliza en la línea anterior...
```

Con ese código, te va a funcionar; sin embargo, es necesario mejorar el manejo de errores para los siguientes casos:

- Más de un archivo tiene el mismo EmisorNombre. En este caso, habría
  archivos duplicados en su nombre y generaría error.
- No se encuentra un EmisorNombre en el archivo.

Ambos casos se deben tratar de acuerdo a alguna regla que tengas definida.